# How to extend Manifest file

Tags: jss

I have created a solution for package importing POC in my local. So, I was following the steps at [Import Pipeline Extension](https://jss.sitecore.net/docs/techniques/working-disconnected/extending-import)

I have projects structure like in screenshot:
[image]

But, I am not sure about step-1 where to perform it after creating the solution. Please suggest me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Step 1 is in your JSS app's `/sitecore/definitions` folder. Any of the component, route, etc definitions in here will work for this. By default `*.sitecore.js` and `*.sitecore.ts` are part of the manifest sourcing.

Step 2 and 3 are done in C#/Sitecore

Step 4 is within the JSS app.

Comment: Thanks @Kam Figy, I was thinking that all things should be in one Visual Studio. But app can reside at different location.

Comment: The JSS app root can - and perhaps should - reside alongside the C# code or at least in the same repository just so deployments can be versioned with Sitecore (avoiding deploying the wrong JSS app version with a different Sitecore backend code version). But they are physically separate concerns; that's kind of the point of 'headless' that they can exist in isolation.